# Partials and VIM

Tags: vim

I have been trying to extract a partial from an application.html.erb file with the following,
:8,14Rextract stylesheets.

I get a return that reads, 'no such directory'.

From this novices perspective, it looks like I am following the example in :help Rextract but then I am never surprised to learn that there is some aspect or other that I am not taking into consideration.

Any help or pointers on how I can get Rextract to work or how to apply it correctly?

Comment: "a partial"? What is that?

Comment: @ldigas, seems to be related to this vim plugin?  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving a full path to the file `stylesheets`?  Perhaps vim changed your CWD to something else and you are getting an error because it can't find what you are trying to specify??

Comment: Hi Zoredache ... thanks for you reply to my posting .... I used the following which is as you suggested, I think. :11,14Rextract layouts/stylesheets ..... and it worked. No surprise to you I suppose but a delightful moment for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi ldigas, I am still learning rails but the understanding I have gleaned thus far is that in the layout that I am currently working on there are two ideas. One of these deals with stylesheets and so it is suggested that you pull out the stylesheets into a partial .... it has a formatted name that starts with _stylesheets and in the original file you replace the lines you have extracted with 'render :partial => 'layouts/stylesheets' .... I guess it is much more than this, but that is my understanding to date.... thanks for you interest.